# MongoDB dump oplog based on timestamp

Tags: backup, mongodb, mongodb-4.0, mongodump

I'm trying to dump `oplog.rs` from local database, based on `timestamp`.
Query directly from mongo shell works but not from mongodump

**Query from mongo shell**

```
RS1:PRIMARY> db.oplog.rs.find({"ts" : {$gt : Timestamp(1591199252, 0)}})
{ "ts" : Timestamp(1591199252, 1), "t" : NumberLong(2), "h" : NumberLong(0), "v" : 2, "op" : "n", "ns" : "", "wall" : ISODate("2020-06-03T15:47:32.975Z"), "o" : { "msg" : "periodic noop" } }
...
```

Mongodump ends either with an `error` or with `0 dumped documents` (depending on single quotes for timestamp value) :
**1. Output with error**

```
$ mongodump $credentials -d local -c oplog.rs --query '{"ts": {"$gt": Timestamp(1591199252, 0)}}' --out ~/test/ 
2020-06-11T16:54:36.317+0200    Failed: error parsing query as Extended JSON: invalid JSON input. Position: 15. Character: T
```

**2. Output with 0 dumped documents**

```
$ mongodump $credentials -d local -c oplog.rs --query '{"ts": {"$gt": "Timestamp(1591199252, 0)"}}' --out ~/test/
2020-06-11T16:59:28.264+0200    writing local.oplog.rs to
2020-06-11T16:59:30.232+0200    done dumping local.oplog.rs (0 documents)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongodump don't understand Timestamp-function, so...

```
mongodump $credentials -d local -c oplog.rs --query '{"ts":{"$timestamp":{"t":1591199252,"i":0}}}' --out /test/
```

Comment: Indeed, I didn't found this part in the doc. Just for information, here is the full query with comparator : `--query '{"ts":{"$gt":{"$timestamp":{"t":1591199252,"i":0}}}}'`